# HMR isn't working after moving files to /app folder

Tags: javascript, express, server, redux, webpack-hmr

Hi I'm currently trying to learn how to use express along with webpacks HMR, and every time I update and save a file it gives me the error:

"The following modules couldn't be hot updated: (Full reload needed)"
"./app/components/App.js"

Is there something wrong with my current config files?

So I have a directory structure like this:

```
todos
    |
    app
      |
    package.son
    server.js
    webpack.config.js
```

and I have a webpack.config.js file and a server.js file that looks like the following:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');


module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname + "/app"),

  entry: ['./index'],
  output: {
    path: "/bundle",
    publicPath: '/static/',
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
     {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  }

};
```

server.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
var webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware')
var webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware')
var config = require('./webpack.config')

var app = new (require('express'))()
var port = 3000

var compiler = webpack(config)
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, { noInfo: true, publicPath: config.output.publicPath }))
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler))

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app/index.html')
})

app.listen(port, function(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error)
  } else {
    console.info("==>   Listening on port %s. Open up http://localhost:%s/ in your browser.", port, port)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried accepting the module? In the Webpack HMR [documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement-with-webpack.html) it says the following:

> A module can only be updated if you “accept” it. So you need to module.hot.accept the module in the parents or the parents of the parents. For example, a router or a subview would be a good place.

Try this in your index.js file or wherever module you want HMR to reload:

```
if (module.hot) {  
 module.hot.accept();
}
```

Comment: But I see the function inside ```module.hot``` is not running at all when data change in the other module that is the child of the parent that have ```module.hot``` checking.